# Run functions for each row in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1`, like this:

```
date        sentence
29/03/1029  I like you
30/03/2019  You eat cake
```

and run functions `getVerb` and `getObj` to dataframe `df1`. So, the output is like this:

```
date        sentence      verb   object
29/03/1029  I like you    like   you
30/03/2019  You eat cake  eat    cake
```

I want those functions (`getVerb` and `getObj`) run for each line in `df1`. Could someone help me to solve this problem in an efficient way?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each column of a pandas `DataFrame` is a `Series`. You can use the `Series.apply` or `Series.map` functions to get the result you want.

```
df1['verb'] = df1['sentence'].apply(getVerb)
df1['object'] = df1['sentence'].apply(getObj)

# OR

df1['verb'] = df1['sentence'].map(getVerb)
df1['object'] = df1['sentence'].map(getObj)
```

See the pandas documentation for more details on [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.Series.apply) or [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.Series.map).

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have a pandas dataframe such as:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
```

df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9]] *3, columns=['A', 'B'])

```
>>>df
   A  B
   4  9
   4  9         
   4  9
```

Let's say, we want sum of columns A and B row wise and column wise. To accomplish it, we write

```
df.apply(np.sum, axis = 1) # for row-wise sum
Output: 13 
        13
        13
df.apply(np.sum, axis = 0) # for column-wise sum
Output: A 12
        B 27
```

Now, if you want to apply any function for specific set of columns, you may choose a subset from the data-frame.

For example: I want to compute sum over column A only.

```
df['A'].apply(np.sum, axis =1)
```

[Dataframe.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply)

You may refer the above link as well. Other than that, Series.map, Series.apply could be handy as well, as mentioned in the above answer.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple loop: (assuming that columns already exist in the data frame having names 'verb' and 'object')

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['verb'].iloc[index]= getVerb(row['sentence'])
    df1['object'].iloc[index]= getObj(row['sentence'])
```